# PowerBI Workspace not visible

Tags: directory, powerbi, workspace, row-level-security

I am trying to give access to a PowerBI(PBI) workspace for an Active Directory(AD) group comprised of few users. When users login to PBI service, they cant see the workspace. The type of the AD group where these users are, set as a Distribution List. There is another separate workspace I created where users in an AD group with type - Mail Enabled Security. Those users can see that Workspace with no issues. Level of permission the AD group was given for this Distribution list PBI workspace was - Viewer. When the users are individually added to this workspace, they can see the workspace. Could someone kindly confirm, if the AD group type has to be a - Mail Enabled Security for the users to see the PowerBI workspace?

According to PowerBI documentation, PBI Workspace also supports AD groups of the type, Distribution List.

See the link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-admin-rls

Thank you for your replies. Much appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCNef.png)

Edited: Hi Andrey, I added an extra image. This I got from a posting in a blog post. It's confusing whether the group has to be security group or a distribution lists are also allowed under PBI workspaces. According to this image, distribution lists are also allowed.

Also want to add that PBI workspace here was created as new workspace type not the Classic type.  Under the point 2 in the link, what that images says confirms by the Microsoft PBI documentation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/collaborate-share/service-give-access-new-workspaces

In order to make it simple, I didn't mention the fact that these groups are being  used to access couple of reports inside the workspace. These reports use roles that maintain Row Level Security. I thought it would still show the users in the group the workspace even though they might not get access to the individual reports inside. Am I too optimistic here?

Edit 2:
Thank you everyone. The issue has been resolved without me doing anything. It was a delay in syncing the changes within the office365/AD accounts/PowerBI it seems. Just for the record I will leave this post here hoping it might help someone with my situation in the future.

Comment: Distribution group is not security enabled group. It is just a list of e-mail addresses. You can't use it for managing permissions, not only in Power BI, but anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrey. I updated the original posting. Hope it's explains the reason for me to use the type as a Distribution List. Based on your reply, I will try changing it to a security group in a few days time and update the outcome . Thanks.